# Should I support 'mysite.com' and 'www.mysite.com'? OpenID Problems?

Tags: asp.net, openid

I implemented OpenID support for an ASP.Net 2.0 web application and everything seems to be working fine on my local machine.

I am using DotNetOpenId library. Before I redirect to the third party website I store the orginal OpenID in the session to use when the user is authenticated (standard practice I believe).

However I have a habit of not typing `www` when entering a URL into the address bar. When I was testing the login on the live server I was getting problems where the session was cleared. My return url was hard coded as www.mysite.com.

Is it possible that switching from `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com` caused the session to switch?

Another issue is that www.mysite.com is not under the realm of mysite.com.

What is the standard solution to these problems. Should the website automatically redirect to `www.mysite.com`? I could just make my link to the log in page an absolute url with containing `www`? Or are these just hiding another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the realm problem that you mentioned is easy.  Just set the realm to *.mysite.com instead of just mysite.com.  If you're using one of the ASP.NET controls included in the library, you just set a property on the control to set the realm.  If you're doing it programmatically, you set the property on the IAuthenticationRequest object before calling RedirectToProvider().

As far as the session/cookie problem goes with hopping between the www and non-www host name, you have two options:

1. Rather than storing the original identifier in the session, which is a bad idea anyway for a few reasons, use the IAuthenticationRequest.AddCallbackArguments(name, value) method to store the user's entered data and then use IAuthenticationResponse.GetCallbackArgument(name) to recall the data when the user has authenticated.
2. Forget it.  There's a reason the dotnetopenid library doesn't automatically store this information for you.  Directed identity is just one scenario: If the user types 'yahoo.com', you probably don't want to say to them 'Welcome, yahoo.com!' but rather 'Welcome, id.yahoo.com/andrewarnott'!  The only way you're going to get the right behavior consistently is to use the IAuthenticationResponse.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay property to decide what to display to the user as his logged in identifier.  It gives more accurate information, and is easier than storing a value in the callback and getting it back. :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use wild cards in the realm.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno how OpenID works, but LiveID gives you a token based on the combination of user and domain.  I just would have forwarded www to mysite.com.

Comment: This seems to be what stackoverflow does.

Answer (score 1):

The cookies and sessions and everything else get lost between www.site.com and site.com.  I don't have patience enough to thoroughly read all the specs, but http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109 states that

> A is a FQDN string and has the form
>   NB, where N is a non-empty name
>   string, B has the form .B', and B' is
>   a FQDN string.  (So, x.y.com 
>   domain-matches .y.com but not y.com.)
>
> Note that domain-match is not a
>   commutative operation: a.b.c.com
>   domain-matches .c.com, but not the
>   reverse.

I think that means yes, you do need to forward to www.  I have always added domain correction code to my sites when cookies and sessions are being used.